# Jquery animation not working after clicking link

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, jquery-animate

I'm just starting out with Jquery and I love it but I've got a problem that I can't wrap my head around.

I've implemented a plugin I purchased which's creates a grid of thumbs which you can then filter on attributes. (trough li class)

In addition I wrote a little piece of code that expands the div on click. This both works perfectly until the menu is used (to filter out by attribute) I understand this may sound a bit vague until you see it so here's the link: 
http://media-surfer.nl/test

If you need all the code pasted here I will do so but since it's a quite a lot I figured best keep overview and visit the link.

I really for the life of me can't figure this out, so any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks a ton in advance :)

here's the code I wrote:

```
<!-- collapse expand jquery -->
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".inhoud").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();

        $('.show_hide').click(function(event) { 

            $(".inhoud").parent().animate({
                width: '160'
            }, 500, function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });

        var $inhoud = $(this).next(".inhoud");

        if($inhoud.hasClass("active")) 
        {
            $(this).parent().animate({
                width: '160'
              }, 500, function() {
                // Animation complete.
            });
            $inhoud.removeClass("active");
        } else {
            $(this).parent().animate({
                width: '769'
              }, 500, function() {
                // Animation complete.
            });
            $inhoud.addClass("active");
        }

    });

});

</script>
 <!-- collapse expand jquery -->
```

Comment: Post the HTML markup also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sooo .. you found a bug on your page ? :D
I think I've used this same sorting plugin once and what it is doing is creating a new collection of elements (matching the sorting criteria) which is then animated. My **guess** is this is the exact reason it breaks the click functionality, since on document ready you bind it to existing elements and by sorting the plugin generates new elements which do not have the click event bound to them. Try using `.on()` by replacing this line:

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(event) {
```

with

```
$(document).on('click','.show_hide', function(event) {
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! really I'm stocked :)
It makes sense that its creating new elements but why isn't the class (which is the click trigger) attached then?

Comment: Because when you use `$('.show_hide').click` on document ready, the document loads and binds the event to all elements which currently have that class. And it ends there. :) If new elements are created they won't have the click listener (even if they match the class). On the other hand, when you bind the listener to the document itself it will always work, since the document is always there.